# Angular setting for file not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my Angular2 application, the organization of the folders is as below

```
Project
 |
 +-- file 1
 |    
 +-- api //folder
 |   |  
 |   | +-- listOfProducts //folder
 |          |
            +-- products.json //file 
 +-- src //folder
 |  |  
 +  | +-- app //folder
          | +-- product //folder
                 +-- product.service.ts
                 +-- product-list.component.ts
                 +-- //other files
```

Now after I run my application I got the following error

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/listOfProducts/products.json 404 (Not Found)
```

how can I access my JSON file? I've tried to move it to Assets folder like:

Project

```
src/assets/api/listOfProducts/products.json //file
```

and I try to access the same URL but it remains the same. This is my angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ang03"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

so what should I do so I can access my JSON file? thanks.

Comment: You can try moving json files into `assets` folder or moving `api` folder into `src` folder, and add `api` into `assets` array.

Comment: I think found the problem I suppose to access the file like http://localhost:4200/assets/api/listOfProducts/products.json 
but is it possible to remove the assets so I can just access it like http://localhost:4200/api/listOfProducts/products.json?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You root folder is `src` based on your angular-cli.json, files outside won't be served.

Comment: but I hear that we can configure it in webpack configuration if I'm not mistaken? but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: no; i guess local json file can be served from assets folder only. I had faced similar problem, then I moved my local json file in assets folder

Comment: I see. guess I have a lot to learn. thanks

Comment: you are accessing your JSON file using HTTP ?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes just for testing that it was at the right location.

Comment: then you have to load from the `assets` folder, and give the path accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - HTTP Service 404. JSON file Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931391/angular-4-http-service-404-json-file-not-found)