# Angular 4 - HTTP Service 404. JSON file Not Found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am having problem in http service.

What i tried is `this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')` as sample data and it works.
But when I used `this.http.get('src/data/employees.json')` it shows me 404 (Not Found)

**employees.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeesService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getEmployees() {
    this.http
      .get('src/employees.json')
      .map((response) => response.json())
      .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeesService } from './employees.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private employeesService: EmployeesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeesService.getEmployees();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes sir i am using it

Comment: @edizonv if you are answer by Kuncevic should work

Comment: @edizonv then answer by Kuncevic will work. I will suggest to follow second approach or you can put all your json files in data folder inside assets so you are not required to modify .angular-cli.json.

Comment: yes it works :) thanks

Comment: here is simple article to fix this issue https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/14/how-to-fix-404-page-not-found-error-after-build-in-angular-or-react-or-vue-js/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using `angular cli` you have to output your json file by setting that up in `.angular-cli.json` like so:

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "src/employees.json"
      ],
```

But I would recommend to create a folder like `data` inside your `src` folder and place all your data `.json` filed in to it. Then have your `assets` config like so:

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "data"
      ],
```

This way cli will alway output the whole `data` folder so you do not have to specify each `.json` file separately

> In case if you changing `.angular-cli.json` during `ng serve` for your
>   changes to take an effect you have to restart `ng serve`

Comment: I already created a data folder in side src folder, and I put the "data" in assets .angular-cli.json file just like what you said, but still the result is 404 not found

Comment: restart you `ng serve`

Comment: thanks it works and i used this this.http.get('data/employees.json')

Comment: @edizonv you should use `this.http.get('data/employees.json')`

Comment: i guess it is gonna be `this.http.get('data/employees.json')` now, but you can always check if file is available just by typing in a browser http://localhost:4201/data/employees.json

Comment: yes it works, thanks a lot wooo hehehe, but what if i have 2 folders that contains json files, employees folder and student folder, should I always declare the folder name in .angula-cli.json file?

Comment: Now you can have as much folders inside`data` folder as you want without configuring each separate but if you want to create any more static folders outside `data` then you have to configure that same way. Also bear in mind that default `angular-cli` static folder called `assets` it is always outputs by default as it is configured in `.angula-cli.json` same way

Comment: alright, I understand it now thanks again to you, I will now go to next step, ill connect it to PHP & MySql :)

Comment: You can add into angular.json if exists. or copy your file into assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're trying to access a file in the "src" directory, which is never made statically available.

If you need to access that json file directly, you need to make sure it's stored in the proper directory in the webserver that it can serve directly (this is usually done by configuring the static/serve settings on the backend).

Just because a file exists in your project folder doesn't mean the webserver makes all of it available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, I placed my angular project in desktop and I tried to create a json file in my localhost this.http.get('http://localhost/data/employees.json') and still 404 not found.   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/data/employees.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: okay, two things i want you to try here. What happens when you directly copy that link into a new tab/window? this will confirm that that's a valid path to the file. Funny enough, I was helping someone out with a similar issue. You shouldn't include the full URI when making HTTP calls to localhost (unless you properly configure your backend to handle CORS). Instead of 'localhost/data/employees.json' it should just be 'data/employees.json' (or '/data/employees.json', i always forget which one it is unfortunately)

Comment: when i  directly copy the link to new window it redirects me to localhost:4200, i tried data/employees.json and /data/employees.json but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Put Your file into `yourProject/src/assets` folder and Give Path like `/assets/yourFilename.json`

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have to navigate into your src folder. Just use `this.http.get('employees.json')` if the file is in your src folder or `this.http.get('data/employees.json')` if you have a data folder in your src folder.

This works because all the code you write in your components or services (or whereever) looks for path relative to your index.html if you omit a leading `/`.

Comment: my json file is in src/data/employees.json that is why i used this.http.get('data/employees.json') but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is probably incorrect. hence the 404 NOT FOUND.

Try editing the path using ../ or ./ or ../../ etc